# How to keep formating with XSL-FO (keeping CR-LF characters)?

Tags: xsl-fo

I'm trying to embed some text into a PDF I generate using XSL-FO/xslt. My text is embedded correctly but the LineFeed and Carriage Returns are removed, so my text file is just a huge block of text.

I'm using **unparsed-text()** to get the content of the text file. I used the **white-space-collapse="false"** to try to get the unformatted text.

```
<fo:block font-family="monospace" white-space-collapse="false" wrap-option="no-wrap">
    <xsl:value-of select="unparsed-text($EXTERNAL_DOCUMENT_FILENAME)" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
</fo:block>
```

Thank you!

===========

## EDIT

I just tried this and I noticed that the output is not formated...

```
<fo:block font-family="monospace" white-space-collapse="false" wrap-option="wrap">
    <!--<xsl:value-of select="unparsed-text($EXTERNAL_DOCUMENT_FILENAME)" />-->
Hi this is me,
Then this is him,

Then I have set the value.

    OK?
</fo:block>
```

I was expecting the exact same text with LF and CR, why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the answer I found:

```
<fo:block font-family="monospace" wrap-option="wrap" linefeed-treatment="preserve" white-space-collapse="false" white-space-treatment="preserve">
    <!--<xsl:apply-templates select="*|text()"/>-->
    <xsl:value-of select='n1:text/text()'/>
</fo:block>
```

This works fine, xsl-fo was removing the CR-LF.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `<xsl:strip-space="yes"/>`.

Also, DOE is not a mandatory feature and in XSLT 2.0 may be supported only for backwards-compatibility features. Try to avoid it.

Try a small text file and see if NL characters are obtained as result of `unparsed-text()` (without XSL-FO at all). If the NL characters are present, then your question is most probably only XSL-FO - related and not XSLT one. If NL characters are not present, then this indicates a bug in your XSLT processor's implementation of `unparsed-text()` -- so contact the vendor and file a bug.